# Apache / .htaccess | Rewriting a URL but the old URL still remains?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have kind of an unusual setup with my website:

- `site.tld` = Gatsby Website with some static pages like /example1 and /example2, etc.
- `site.tld/blog` = A WordPress website

Now I wanted to have users visit a new page `site.tld/mynewpage` which ACTUALLY is a page on the WordPress website. So the actual URL is `site.tld/blog/mynewpage`.

To achieve that I have defined this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^mynewpage/$ /blog/mynewpage/ [L]
```

Which kind of works. It lets me successfully see the desired wordpress page, when I browse to `site.tld/mynewpage`.

My expactation would've been that if I now browse to `site.tld/blog/mynewpage`, it would either give me a 404 or it would "auto-redirect" to `site.tld/mynewpage`. But none of that happens. The address bar still says `site.tld/blog/mynewpage` and I see that page correctly. So now I have two links pointing to `mynewpage`. For SEO thats not a big deal, since I can set the canonical URL to be `site.tld/mynewpage`, but it bothers me, that this "old URL" `site.tld/blog/mynewpage` is still around.

Is there a way to fix that? I naively tried to do a redirect from `site.tld/blog/mynewpage` to `site.tld/mynewpage` but that gave me a "too many redirects", which I think is because it's an infinite loop.

Any help appreciated =)

Comment: Presumably you have 2 `.htaccess` files? One in the root and the other in the `/blog` subdirectory? In your examples you do not have a trailing slash on the URLs (ie. `/mynewpage`), however, in the directive you posted you have included a trailing slash (ie. `/mynewpage/`) - which is it?

Comment: Yes it's two as you said, and the trailing slash is already handled, I didn't have any problem with that yet. But yes, it's actually WITH trailing slash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure you only redirect "direct" requests back to the root and not the *rewritten* request by your existing rewrite in the root `.htaccess` file (which will result in a redirect loop).

Add the following to the *top* of the `/blog/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^mynewpage/$ /$0 [R=301,L]
```

This assumes the URL has a trailing slash, as in your "working" rewrite directive. However, all your examples have omitted the trailing slash?

At first glance, this might "look" like it's redirecting to the *same* URL, however, because the `.htaccess` file is in the subdirectory it does remove the subdirectory from the redirected URL. ie. It redirects from `/blog/mynewpage/` to `/mynewpage/`.

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches the URL-path *relative* to the location of the `.htaccess` file. So, since we are in the `/blog` subdirectory, the regex `^mynewpage/$` matches a request for `/blog/mynewpage/`. And we redirect back to `/mynewpage/` using the `$0` backreference, which contains the URL-path that was matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

The check against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable ensures that only direct requests (from the client) are redirected and not rewritten requests by your existing rewrite.

NB: Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid caching issues.

Answer (score 1):

Add 301 redirection to your old URL - `site.tld/blog/mynewpage` to `site.tld/mynewpage`

301 redirection can be added via .htaccess like below

```
Redirect 301 /oldurl/ http://www.example.com/newurl/
```

or you can try using the below code if you have custom php page

```
<?php
header("Location: https://www.example.com/newurl", true, 301);
exit();
?>
```

Comment: I will try with your code, but that is what I actually tried already, giving me "too many redirects" because it's an infinite loop.

Comment: Check existing redirects on your webpages or check your htaccess redirects.